# How to get Array Data using BeautifulSoup from a Source Code?

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

What I'm trying to do here is to those values after "=>"
Is it possible to be made with BeautifulSoup ?

This is what is in the source code:

```
<!-- <pre style="text-align: left">Array
(
[vl_lance_order] => R$ 34.000
[data_leilao] => 17-07-2015 - 10h00 
[nm_identificacao] => 
[incremento_minimo] => 2000
[incremento_sistema] => 2000.00
[mensagem] => FOTOS ATUALIZADAS
[segmento_id] => 667740
[dt_inicioleilaoonline] => 2015-07-13
[nm_img] => C667740A.JPG;C667740B.JPG;C667740C.JPG;C667740D.JPG;C667740E.JPG;C667740F.JPG
[nu_contadorvisita] => 921
[vl_multiplo] => 0.00
[ordenacao] => 0
[nm_deposito] => Curitiba
[numlances] => 14
[cli] => 1230
[nm_cliente] => BANCO MERCEDES-BENZ S.A
[link] => /leilao/12240/lote/1485951/segmento/veiculos/ordenacao/data_leilao/tipo-ordenacao/crescente/qtde-itens/15/visualizacao/visual_imagem/item-atual/1/pagina/1/
)
</pre> -->
```

Yes, it is commented.

What I have so far is:

```
url = 'https://www.example.com'
source_code = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.content, "html5lib")
```

Other solutions besides using BeautifulSoup are welcome.
tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If source code will always be same form like you provided, why don't you consider just split it into lines, and split it again with `"=>"`?

```
for line in src.split("\n"):
    segs = line.split("=>")
    if len(segs) == 2:
        key = segs[0].strip().replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
        value = segs[1].strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do like this?

- Iterate over all the lines.
- Find the lines which contain `=>` symbol.
- Then do splitting on `=>` symbol and then print the index 1 of splitted list.